# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.( SPWebApplication.Update)

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, policy

I get this error when trying to add user policy whithin sharepoint 2010 web application programmatically:

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

Here's a code sample:

```
public Boolean AddUser(SoftwareUser user)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                using (web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPUser spUser = web.EnsureUser(user.UserShortname);
                    web.Groups["MySolution Members"].AddUser(spUser);
                    if (spUser != null)
                    {
                        if (user.Email != null)
                        {
                            spUser.Email = user.Email;
                        }
                        spUser.Update();
                        SPWebApplication webApp = site.WebApplication;
                        SPPolicy policy = webApp.Policies.Add(spUser.Name, "deny");
                        policy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add(webApp.PolicyRoles["deny"]);
                        webApp.Update();
                    }
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

---

Find below the stacktrace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Update()
at WcfServices.WFService.<>c__DisplayClass2c.<AddUser>b__2b() in C:\SourceCode\DEV-_V5.2.5\WCFServices\SP2010\WcfServices\WcfServices\WFService.svc.cs:line 980
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
at WcfServices.WFService.AddUser(SoftwareUser user) in C:\SourceCode\DEV-_V5.2.5\WCFServices\SP2010\WcfServices\WcfServices\WFService.svc.cs:line 959
at SyncInvokeAddUser(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: At what line you are getting error?

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT call `.Update()` inside Evelvated Permission’s delegate
Just do it below `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`